# Suddenly cannot read property DateAxisRenderer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqplot

After some weeks, my jqPlot suddenly stopped working.

My Chrome return error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateAxisRenderer' of
>   undefined.

I've never faced this problem before. Any hints, guys?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var month = <?php echo $month ;?>;
    var maxDay = <?php echo $maxDay;?>;
    var max = <?php echo $max;?>;
    var min = <?php echo $min;?>;
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($all_data) ?>;
    var arr = new Array(maxDay);

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(2);
        arr[i][0] = data[i]['date'];
        arr[i][1] = data[i]['total'];
    }
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', [arr], {

      title:'Month ' + month ,
        axes:{
          xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
              formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
            },
            tickInterval : '1 days'
          },
          yaxis:{
            tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%.2f'
          },
          min:min,
          max:max
        }
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 2
      },
      cursor: {
        show: false
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have the `jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js` plugin included?

Comment: Yes i have done it, sir with <script type="text/javascript" src="../realistic/layout/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>     a week ago my chart was working but after I accessed it today suddenly it stop working.

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. It says `$.jqplot is undefined`. Please confirm this by trying `console.log($.jqplot);` If it outputs undefined, then you're missing some file inclusion. Check your script paths, and verify in your network tab that all the script files are being correctly loaded. Also, make sure to load jqplot after jQuery.

Comment: @JeremyThille console show undefined and no missing inclusion sir, neither the file. All is correct but still won't work. So I just move this file to my last week project backup and it's working. When I moved the backup file to my current project(reverse), it ain't work. Any idea?

Comment: So I found the problem sir, I include() a file that require jquery too, seems like the file cause the collisions. Thanks for the response, sir.